# Denial of entry in Japan because no visa. Can I sue the airline?

Tags: japan, denial-of-entry

Last month I was traveling to Japan with my husband and my brother in law for visit from USA. Immigration officers let my husband and my brother in law entry into the country,but they not let me in due absence of visa. My question is who’s responsible for this? Do airline for this?

Comment: I've removed the US citizens tag added by Mikael as the OP doesn't specify their nationality, and US citizens don't need a visa to enter Japan

Comment: The airline should probably have noticed when you checked in or boarded, but their responsibility is only towards the destination country, not you. Still, can you clarify your citizenship?

Answer (score 9):

You are the only person responsible for ensuring that you have proper visas to enter a country. While many airlines flying to some locations ask passengers if they have the correct visa before they fly, the airlines do not have to do this [edit, they do, but that is an obligation they have to the destination country, not the traveller, and travellers are due no compensation if a mistake is made]. Before you travel anywhere you must check your destination's visa requirements or this will keep happening to you.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Japan

Comment: "the airlines do not have to do this": actually, in many cases if not most, airlines are liable for a substantial fine if they being someone to a country who does not have the correct documents.

Comment: @phoog I didn't realise that! Apologies. Still, that is an obligation that the airline has to the arrival country, not an obligation that the airline has to the passenger. It's still the passenger's responsibility to have proper permissions to enter a country and they cannot sue the airline for this.

Comment: I agree completely.  I mention it mainly because we get occasional questions here that misinterpret the airline's obligation to the destination country as an obligation to the traveler.  It's important to recognize that the obligation exists and also that it doesn't remove from the traveler the burden to know what visas are necessary and to obtain them before traveling.

Comment: @Andy yes, that's precisely the point, but for some reason people seem to continue to misunderstand.

Answer (score 8):

You can't sue the airline.

Check your documentation that you received when you booked your tickets. You will find somewhere a clause that explicitly states that you are responsible for ensuring you have all the required documentation for your trip, including any visas that may be required.

You haven't said what happened after you were denied entry, but I imagine that the airline flew you back to your point of origin. The airline will have incurred costs in doing this, and they might also have been fined by the Japanese authorities. It's possible (but I don't know how likely) that they might come to you for the money.